# numpy: slicing and vectorized looping with 1d and 2d arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, slice

I want to vectorize the following loops for efficiency:

```
A = np.array([[0., 1., 0., 2.],
              [1., 0., 3., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0., 4.],
              [2., 0., 4., 0.]]) # quadratic, not symmetric Matrix, shape (i, i)
B = np.array([2., 4., 2., 1.]) # vector shape (i)
C = np.zeros(A.shape) # Result Matrix 
# classical Loop:
for i in range(len(B)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
        C[i, j] = A[i, j]*(B[i]-B[j])
```

My first attempt, that uses vectorisation like in Mathcad, does not what I want:

```
i = np.arange(len(B))
j = np.arange(len(B))
C[i,j] = A[i,j]*(B[i]-B[j]) # this fails to do what I want
```

Is my second attempt the best way t do it, or is there an easier more natural "numpy way"?

```
idx = np.indices(A.shape)
C[idx] = A[idx]*(B[idx[0]]-B[idx[1]])
```

Comment: can you please edit the post modifying `B = np.array[2., 4., 2., 1.]` into `B = np.array([2., 4., 2., 1.])`? (I don't have the reputation to do such a small edi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
A = np.array([[0., 1., 0., 2.],
             [1., 0., 3., 0.],
             [0., 0., 0., 4.],
             [2., 0., 4., 0.]]) # quadratic, not symmetric Matrix, shape (i, i)
B = np.array([2., 4., 2., 1.]) # vector shape (i)

C = A*(B[:,None]-B)
```

C is

```
array([[ 0., -2.,  0.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 0., -0.,  0.,  4.],
       [-2., -0., -4.,  0.]])
```

A little explanation:
`B[:,None]` converts `B` to a column vector of shape `[4,1]`. `B[:,None]-B` automatically broadcast the result to a 4x4 matrix that you can simply multiply by `A`